# what's wrong with this zend framework error?

Tags: php, zend-framework, exception

so I encountered this error from Zend Framework:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 
'Zend_Loader_PluginLoader_Exception' with message 
'Plugin by name 'FrontUIHelper' was not found in the registry; 
used paths: ZendX_JQuery_View_Helper_: ZendX/JQuery/View/Helper/ hlp_:
/home/public_html/application/views/helpers/ Zend_View_Helper_:
Zend/View/Helper/:./views/helpers/:/home/public_html/application/views/helpers/' 
in /home/public_html/library/Zend/Loader/PluginLoader.php:412 Stack trace: #0 
/home/public_html/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php(1170): 
Zend_Loader_PluginLoader->load('FrontUIHelper') #1 
/home/public_html/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php(610): 
Zend_View_Abstract->_getPlugin('helper', 'frontUIHelper') #2 
/home/public_html/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php(336): 
Zend_View_Abstract->getHelper('frontUIHelper') #3 
/home/public_html/application/layouts/layout.phtml(18): 
Zend_View_Abstract->__call('frontUIHelper', Array) #4 
/home/public_html/application/layouts/layout.phtml(18): 
Zend_View->frontUIHelper() #5 
/h in /home/public_html/library/Zend/Loader/PluginLoader.php  
on line 412
```

What am I doing wrong? How to resolve this problem?

thanks in advance

Comment: Adding some code on how you're adding/calling the Zend Library might help out as well. Did you include the path to the Zend Library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that there are no file with this class. Or it is no class in this file. Check names. Are autoloader included to the index.php? Are you added ZendX namespace to your autoloader? Zend Framework autoloader based on class names.